# How to access nested data in Arrays and Objects with Javascript

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I am tring to use react-charts and the object they give as example data looks like this.

```
chartData: [
  {
    label: 'Series 1',
    data: [
      [0, 1],
      [1, 2],
      [2, 4],
      [3, 2],
      [4, 7],
    ],
  },
],
```

I want to build my own "data" and replace this temporary data but the whole object of arrays in objects in arrays (Or whatever it is confuses me.

Can someone explain the nesting here.
Is it an array of 2 objects `label` and `data and` data` is an array of key value pairs. Is that accurate?

I'm kind of trying something like this...

```
   let myData = []
   res.data.payload.forEach(function (item, index) {
      console.log(item, index)
      myData[(index, item.odds)]
   })
   this.setState({ chartData[data]: myData })
```

Am I even close?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
   let myData = []
   res.data.payload.forEach(function (item, index) {
      console.log(item, index)
      myData.push([index, item.odds])
   })
   this.setState({ chartData: [{...this.state.chartData[0], data: myData}] })
```

Comment: Key thing is to create new chartData array object.

Comment: try to console log myData

Comment: Sorry you had charData not chartData. All fixed Thank you!